# How to turn flutter seconds into minutes and seconds

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote a code that counts down from 240 seconds to 0 second in the Flutter app.
But only seconds come out here.
All I want is to have minutes and seconds represented

```
int _Counter = 240;
  late Timer _timer;

  void startTimer(){
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer){
      if(_Counter > 0){
        setState(() {
          _Counter--;
        });
      }else{
        _timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }
```

ex)

- 240 = 04:00
- 200 = 03:20
- 60 = 01:00
- 10 = 00:10
- 0 = 00:00

I don't know how to solve it.
Can someone give me a solution or tell me how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to manage it after counter decrementing, look at bellow,

```
void startTimer() {
  _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    if (_counter > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _counter--;
        timerText(); // Call timerText function after decrementing counter
      });
    } else {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
  });
}

String timerText() {
  int minutes = _counter ~/ 60;
  int seconds = _counter % 60;
  return '${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
}
```

In this modification, `timerText` is now a function that returns a formatted string representing the remaining time. Inside the `startTimer` function, we call `timerText()` immediately after decrementing the counter within the `setState` callback. This ensures that the displayed time gets updated each time the counter decrements.

with milliseconds,

```
int _counter = 240;
late Timer _timer;

void startTimer() {
  _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) { // Adjust duration to 10 milliseconds
    if (_counter > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _counter -= 10; // Decrement by 10 milliseconds
        timerText(); // Call timerText function after decrementing counter
      });
    } else {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
  });
}

String timerText() {
  int minutes = _counter ~/ 60000; // Convert milliseconds to minutes
  int seconds = (_counter ~/ 1000) % 60; // Convert milliseconds to seconds
  int milliseconds = (_counter % 1000) ~/ 10; // Extract milliseconds
  return '${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${milliseconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
}
```

- In this new update with`enter code here`, I've adjusted the
  startTimer function to decrement the counter by 10 milliseconds
  `_counter -= 10` and the `Timer.periodic` duration to 10 milliseconds
  `Duration(milliseconds: 10)`.
- Then, I've updated the `timerText` function to calculate minutes,
  seconds, and milliseconds accordingly.

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved it without difficulty.
I want to have "millisseconds" come out, but it doesn't work.
int milliseconds = _Counter % 1000;

Can you solve this as well?

Comment: yes I will update

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the minutes, you must divide the seconds by 60. To calculate the remaining seconds, you must subtract the minutes from the seconds. You can then use [padLeft](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/padLeft.html) to place a zero in front of a number if it only has one digit.

```dart
String formatTime(int seconds) {
  final minutes = seconds ~/ 60;
  final remainingSeconds = seconds - minutes * 60;
  return '${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${remainingSeconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Package intl has [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html).  You can turn DateTime into any format you want.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  const seconds = 185; // for example
  final df = DateFormat.ms();
  // construct a DateTime that reliably has proper HMS:
  final d = DateTime.utc(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, seconds);
  final printString = df.format(d);
  print(printString);
}
```